# Does an open map of the real line have to be one to one?

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples

Is it true or not that open map $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a one one map?  If it is one one explain how it is one one.

Comment: Well the image is connected and therefore an interval.  If $f(a)=f(b)$ then then think about what happens to the interval $(a,b)$, the image must have a finite sup or inf.

Comment: There are functions whose range on any nonempty open interval is all of $\Bbb R$. See Gelbaum and Olmsted, *Counterexamples in Analysis*, example 27, Chapter 8 pg. 104. (This may be overkill.)

Comment: its very long example..

Comment: please explain....

Comment: but if we define any value at zero it will not be open..